# How to get test assertions stats in playwright json reporting

Tags: playwright

Using  `['json', { outputFile: 'test-results.json' }]` I can get reporting in JSON:

```
"stats": {
  "startTime": "2024-01-16T00:12:01.124Z",
  "duration": 156.64900000111106,
  "expected": 10,
  "skipped": 0,
  "unexpected": 1,
  "flaky": 0
}
```

I get stats at test level, is it possible to get stats like total assertions passed or failed either at individual test level or suite tests?

I tried getting stats from Allure and HTML report but no where I was able to get assertions stats.

Comment: Does the supplied answer clear up your concerns?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this isnt something that is do-able without some complex custom logic.

Playwright recommends assertions to perform actions such as wating (toBeVisible) etc, getting locator counts etc so even if it was an inbuilt stat that can be reported against, I wouldn't see any reason it could be used. It would be widely skewed due to the above usage of assertions for much more than just expecting x to be y.

As such, said option would have no utility. Your tests should check for a certain state to be reached, and pass if reached or fail if not. Use the pass rates as the metric to determine your results, not assertion counts, as this will never give any type of guidance on accuracy, or test performance.